# Draggable scroll and potential issues on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have horizontally scrolling panel (via `overflow-x:scroll`) and user should be able to scroll it by dragging (not just scrollbar, but the content itself too).

Using some draggable carousel library (e.g. [owlcarousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)) isn't an option as all of them use transforms instead of native scroll.

So my plan is:

- bind `mousedown` event
- change horizontal scroll offset on `mousemove`
- stop all actions at `mouseup`

All is good on desktop. But the problem is mobile, as mobile browsers trigger fake `mousedown` and `mousemove` events - the scrolling is corrupted. If I call `preventDefault` in `touchstart/move` - fake mouse events stop firing, but pane isn't scrolling either.

Is there any way to prevent fake `mousedown/move/up` events on mobile without calling `e.preventDefault()`?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: "If I call preventDefault in touchstart/move - fake mouse events stop firing, but pane isn't scrolling either." I still think this the right solution. Do some debug logging to see why the scrolling isn't working.

Comment: @Thomas calling preventDefault in touchstart/move disables browser scroll (both main, and my horizontal pane).

Comment: Oh, I thought you were running your own scrolling algorithm on touch events as well. But indeed it would be nicer to let the browser take care of that, if possible.

Comment: @Thomas I guess there is an option to use PointerEvents that allows to determine between mouse and toucn pointer. The problem is that Safari doesn't support it, and I don't know what to do about it...

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/touch-events/#mouse-events):

> To avoid processing the same interaction twice for touch (once for the touch event, and once for the compatibility mouse events), developers should make sure to cancel the touch event, suppressing the generation of any further mouse or click events. Alternatively, see the [InputDeviceCapabilities API](http://wicg.github.io/InputDeviceCapabilities/) for a way to detect mouse events that were generated as a result of touch events.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be available in any browser (yet?).

---

A more viable possibility is to [disable touch scrolling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) on your element, and letting your mouse handling code take care of the scrolling:

```
.my-panel {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

---

If this makes scrolling too janky on mobile, a hacky but possibly effective solution might be to ignore any `mousemove` event that follows shortly (say, within 100 ms) after a `touchmove` event.